# How do I tell the difference between +'s in and out of strings?

Tags: c#, parsing

I am making a simple compiler, and am working on string parsing. At the moment, my code is:

```cs
    while (stringToParse.Contains(" + ") || stringToParse.Contains("+ ") || stringToParse.Contains(" +")) {
        stringToParse = stringToParse.Replace(" +", "+").Replace("+ ", "+").Replace(" + ", "+");
    }
    string[] splitString = stringToParse.Split("+");
```

---

But something like:

```
"\"hello \" + \"world \" + \" + \" + \"hello\""
```

Would return:

```
["\"hello "\", "\"world \"", "\"", "\"", ]
```

---

(without backslashes)

But something like:

```
""hello " + "world " + " + " + "hello""
```

Would return:

```
[""hello "", ""world "", """, """, ]
```

---

So how can I specify if a `" + "` is in a string or as a separator? is there maybe a way to detect for something like the following?

```
...(any number of non " or + characters)...+...(any number of " or + characters)
```

My expected output would be:

```
[""hello "", ""world "", ""+""]
```

Comment: Can you please put your input without /. in a different line, as well as expected out put

Comment: Does c# have string templates or something like template literals? I'd rather eat rocks than deal with string concatenation.

Comment: This is why real-world parsers do not use `String.Split()`

Comment: @zero298 I feel the same. I dont know, and I sure hope it does.

Comment: @BenVoigt, ok, would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Usually there's a tokenizer first, followed by recursive descent, LALR, or similar to build the abstract syntax tree.  See examples from tools like `flex` (successor to `lex`) and `bison` (successor to `yacc`)

Comment: @BenVoigt how can I get started? I only understood half the words in that sentence... like wheres a good starting point?

Comment: Just an excercise for you (sorry!): Which of the three `stringToParse.Contains` is redundant here in your expression `(stringToParse.Contains(" + ") || stringToParse.Contains("+ ") || stringToParse.Contains(" +"))` ? (No need to solve it if you don't want, i am not forcing you, nor do i dispense any points or grades ;-) )

Comment: @elgonzo \*facepalm\* the first I dont know what I was thinking...

Comment: I know what you were thinking. The same like me: "_Thank god it's weekend!_" ;-P

Comment: @elgonzo hahaha

Comment: You can probably find better ones (if you put more time into searching than I did), but this seems to be a tutorial of acceptable quality that will introduce you to the terminology of parsers and give you an idea about how they express the languages they parse: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/

Comment: If you want to minimize theory and just get something minimal but capable working quickly, here's a tutorial on recursive descent parsers, including parentheses (which gets you 90% of the way to quoted strings since both are paired): https://www.strchr.com/expression_evaluator   The language is C++ not C#, but they aren't using any advanced C++ features so I think you can follow along.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, I'll check that out.

Comment: For starting with compiler you can take a look on this video. It can give you the idea of how to create a lexer from a grammar, the the parser and finally use an ast to visit your nodes. grahttp://usergroup.tv/videos/dsl-using-antlr-and-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### Explicit State Machine

To do this, *Without using any dedicated library*, I suggest to build a state machine.

You will iterate over the characters of the string, and depending on which character you encounter you update the state of the machine. *Optimizations are possible, however, let us begin with conventional clarity.*

```
var characters = input.ToCharArray();
var results = new List<string>();
var current = string.Empty;

// 0 = not inside quotes, we expect +
// 1 = not inside quotes, we expect "
// 2 = inside quotes
var state = 1;

foreach (var character in characters)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0:
            // We are not inside quotes, we expect +
            if (character == '+')
            {
                state = 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // error?
            break;
        case 1:
            // We are not inside quotes, we expect "
            if (character == '\"')
            {
                state = 2;
                continue;
            }
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // error?
            break;
        case 2:
            // We are inside quotes, we expect "
            if (character == '\"')
            {
                state = 0;
                results.Add(current);
                current = string.Empty;
                continue;
            }
            current += character;
            break;
        default:
            // error?
            break;
    }
}

if (state != 0)
{
    // error
}

// You can use results.ToArray();
```

Possible optimizations:

- We can use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) instead of concatenations.
- Also, we can use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) to find the next relevant character.
- We can check if a string (a chunk of characters) is empty or white space (perhaps using [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)).
- We can use [AsSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.internal.system.spanextensions.asspan?view=aspnetcore-2.0) so we can work with [ReadOnlySpan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/25/c-7-series-part-10-spant-and-universal-memory-management/) instead.

You can also see how you can add support for your own escape sequences, or any other stuff.

---

### Implicit State Machine (with helper class)

I want to point out that this is not the only way to organize this code. I would, if I were you, create a pseudo iterator class that had a method two methods:

- A method that returns the next character... or better yet, that returns true if the next character matches a parameter (and advances), or false (and does not advance).
- A method that returns all the characters until the next instance of a particular character (and advances to there).

The main advantage of such approach is that I would no longer have to step character by character, thus, I would not need to have a `state` variable. Instead I could allow the code structure to resemble the shape of my gramar.

*Wait, I have wrote such class: [StringProcessor](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/blob/master/Framework.Core/Theraot/Core/StringProcessor.cs). It is part of the [Theraot.Core nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Theraot.Core/), it is used to parse strings to BigInteger.*

```
var processor = new Theraot.Core.StringProcessor(input);
var results = new List<string>();

while (!processor.EndOfString)
{
    // SkipWhile skips all the characters that match
    processor.SkipWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace);
    // Read returns true (and advances after) if what is next matches the paramter
    if (processor.Read('"'))
    {
        // ReadUntil advances after and returns everything found before the parameter 
        // Note: it does not advance after the parameter.
        results.Add(processor.ReadUntil('"'));
        processor.Read('"'); 
    }
    processor.SkipWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace);
    if (!processor.Read('+'))
    {
        // error?
    }
}
```

Please notice that a class such as the `StringProcessor` used above cuts a lot of fluff, which makes it viable for simple languages.

---

### Custom Tokenizer

Of course, for something more complex you might want to look for a tokenizer.

To give you an example, consider that this is the "grammar" we have:

```
Document: Many
{
    Whitespace
    String:
    {
        QuoteSymbol
        NonQuoteSymbol
        QuoteSymbol
    }
    Whitespace
    PlusSymbol
}
```

No, this not any of the usual metalanguages. However, written this way it is easier to see how the code we had above resembles the language.

Would it not be nice to write as follows?

```
var QuoteSymbol = Pattern.Literal("QuoteSymbol", '"');
var NonQuoteSymbol = Pattern.Custom("NonQuoteSymbol", s => s.ReadUntil('"'));
var String = Pattern.Conjunction("String", QuoteSymbol, NonQuoteSymbol, QuoteSymbol);

var WhiteSpace = Pattern.Custom("WhiteSpace", s => s.ReadWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace));
var PlusSymbol = Pattern.Literal("PlusSymbol", '+');
var Document = Pattern.Repetition(
    Pattern.Conjunction(WhiteSpace, String, WhiteSpace, PlusSymbol)
);

var results = from TerminalSymbol symbol
              in Document.Parse(input)
              where symbol.Pattern == String
              select symbol.ToString();
```

Writing code like that would make it easier to modify the language. *Well, we are still writing code, however you could imagine parsing a file that has the grammar of the language you want to parse... Fancy!*

As you might expect, it requires extra work to build the necesary code to make it work. Or, you know, get [some code that already works](https://gist.github.com/theraot/e07af2f8d3acae3f33eb47f0698865c4) (the linked code is built around on `StringProcessor`).

---

### Language Toolkits

The code presented earlier is not suitable to be used for a [prettyprinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) and is not capable of recovering from a syntax error. *It can be modified to do such things.* Neither will it integrate with code editors at any level.

If you want a fully fledged solution. I have two suggestions:

- [Irony](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Irony)
- [Nitra](https://github.com/rsdn/nitra)

These are the kind of things you would use if you wanted to create a programming language ontop.

---

And of course, I should link you to ["Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) usually just known as "The Dragon Book".

Comment: I would suggest using the visitor pattern if going for tokenization. It is good for compilers, and can build on the techniques you are proposing. A modern pattern for it is here: https://blogs.u2u.be/kris/post/Farewell-Visitor . It would facilitate crawling symbols and doing different things per symbol. It also facilitates new symbols being introduced without modifications (ie open and closed principle)

Comment: @Dessus I agree we could build a tokenizer on top of what I have in the answer at the moment of writing, and that using the visitor pattern can be useful in that situation. However, what you link is not parsing a string, it is processing an expression tree.

Comment: True, but you could put a string into an expression tree (or go for a standard visitor pattern).

Comment: thanks! I dont know if I will be able to truly utilize this information, as I am new to programming, but I think this is a good starting point. thanks again!